Evaluating this intriguing sum of harmonic numbers
Any idea whether a known function can be used to describe this sum:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_{k-1}-H_{k-1/2}}{16k^2-1}\,,\tag{1}$$
with $n>0$ and $H_n$ the harmonic numbers? I am interested in a closed form.
What I have tried:
For each $n$ the expression takes the form
$$f(n) = a(n) + b(n) \log 4\,.\tag{2}$$
It is possible to find a closed form the $b(n)$:
$$b(n) = \frac{1}{8} \bigl(-\psi^{(0)}(3/4) + \psi^{(0)}(5/4) + \psi^{(0)}(3/4 + n) - \psi^{(0)}(5/4 + n)\bigr)\,, \tag{3}$$
with $\psi^{(n)} (m)$ the polygamma function. I was not so successful for $a(n)$, for which I find another finite sum:
$$a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16 k^2 -1} \bigl( -2 + \gamma + \psi^{(0)}(3/2) + \psi^{(0)}(k) - \psi^{(0)}(1/2 + k) \bigr)\,, \tag{4}$$
with $\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni number. It is a bit of a circular thing, since $(4)$ has a similar form to $(1)$ at the end.

What's so interesting about this particular sum? Could you add a bit of background/context?

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

@abomasnow Consider $H_k$ as the analytic continuation between integers, for instance Mathematica plots $H_k$ continuously between $0$ and $1$ (and above).

@AnneBauval I added one (unsuccessful) attempt. Is it better now?

@mathsisart This sum appears in calculations of Feynman integrals in quantum field theory, in a setup where symmetry is partially broken. This sum is the hardest term of the calculation of the observable, and it seems to be the one that is the most symptomatic of the breaking of symmetry.

If you take into account the relation between the digamma function and the generalized harmonic numbers
$$b(n)=\frac{1}{8} \left(H_{n-\frac{1}{4}}-H_{n+\frac{1}{4}}+4-\pi \right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici Indeed. This is also because of this relation that I say that my attempt is (kind of) circular.

I agree with you about the circular aspect.

we have
$$ f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_{k-1}-H_{k-\frac{1}{2}}}{16k^2-1}=a(n)+b(n)\ln 4 $$
but by digamma function we have
$$ H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}=\gamma+\psi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\ln4+\sum_{p=1}^n \frac{2}{2p-1}$$
So
$$ f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16k^2-1}\left(H_{k-1}+\ln 4-\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{2}{2p-1}\right)$$
or
$$ f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16k^2-1}\left(H_{k-1}-\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{2}{2p-1}\right)+\ln 4\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16k^2-1} $$
So we get
$$a(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16k^2-1}\left(H_{k-1}-\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{2}{2p-1}\right) \\ b(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{16k^2-1}$$
The function b(n) can indeed be expressed using the digamma function, as you demonstrated. However, I find this approach less appealing because the digamma function at rational arguments is more complicated than a simple summation of rational numbers. As for a(n), it seems there isn’t a more straightforward expression that avoids the use of summation.
